# Closed form expression for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty H(x - n y) z^n$ involving Heaviside functions

Tags: summation, distribution-theory, step-function

For $x>0$, $y>0$ and $0 < z < 1$ consider the sum
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty H(x - n y) z^n\ ,
$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. Is there a way to write down a closed form expression for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sum of a finite geometric progression: $$\sum_{n:x\geq yn,n\geq0}{z^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\right\rfloor}{z^n}=\frac{z^{\left\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\right\rfloor+1}-1}{z-1}$$